# LongListSelector Empty View when no items are available

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

is there anything comparable to the [Empty View of Android Lists](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivity_layout) when I'm using the LongListSelector in WP8? My app loads data from the internet and when there is initially no data available, I want to display a message to the user that the list is currently empty.

I would like to avoid a solution which includes other views which are only visible when the list is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it need to be in the list?
I mostly put a textblock above the list and hide it when data is/comes available...

Comment: I've gone this way now. I've created a bool property IsListEmpty and set it to true or false in the setter of the List property depending on the count of elements in the list I want to watch. So if (list.count > 0) {IsListEmpty = false} else {IsListEmpty = true}

Comment: Small extra, for a common listbox I found this [http://metronuggets.com/2012/03/01/phonelistbox-control-for-windows-phone](http://metronuggets.com/2012/03/01/phonelistbox-control-for-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a datatemplate selector and add a textblock which says "No data available" or something to the LongListSelector.
http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector

Comment: That is certainly a nice solution to display different types of items, but I want a solution which displays text to the user when there are no items at all in my list (e.g. when there is no data downloaded yet).

Comment: Well you could still use that method. When the page loads add an item to the longlistselector that's simply a textblock saying "No items available" and when the real data is downloaded remove the previous item from the longlistselector and add your real data.